# Pandas Error - Appending multiple files into one

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, append

I have a set of files that do not have any extension. They are currently stored in a folder that is referenced by this variable "allFiles".

```
allFiles = glob.glob(base2 + "/*")
```

I am trying to add an extension to each of the files in allFiles. Add .csv to the file name. I do it using the below code:

```
for file in allFiles:
    os.rename(os.path.join(base2, file), os.path.join(base2, file+'.csv'))
```

Next I try to append each of these csv files into one as per the below code.

```
list_ = []
    for file_ in allFiles:
        try:
            df = pd.read_csv(file_, index_col=None, header=None,delim_whitespace = True, error_bad_lines=False)
            list_.append(df)
        except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
            continue
```

When I run the above code, I get an error stating one of the files do not exist.

```
Error : FileNotFoundError: File b'/Users/base2/file1' does not exist
```

But file1 has now been renamed to file1.csv

Could anyone advice as to where am I going wrong in the above. Thanks

Update:

```
allFiles = glob.glob(base2 + "/*")
print(allFiles)
list_ = []
print(list_)
allFiles = [x + '.csv' for x in allFiles]
print(allFiles)
for file_ in allFiles:
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(file_, index_col=None, header=None)
        list_.append(df)
    except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
        continue

Error : FileNotFoundError: File b'/Users/base2/file1.csv' does not exist
```

Comment: Did you try executing `allFiles = glob.glob(base2 + "/*")` again after you renamed the files?

Comment: Initially, you were changing your file names, but not changing the strings in your array.

With your update, you're now changing the strings in your allFiles array, but you're not changing your file names. 

You need to do both.

Comment: @wwii your comment helped me overcome this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before running your loop, do:

EDIT for clarity:

```
for file in allFiles:
    os.rename(os.path.join(base2, file), os.path.join(base2, file+'.csv'))

###What you're adding###
allFiles = [x+'.csv' for x in allFiles]
########################

for file_ in allFiles:
    try:
```

Basically, the problem is that you're changing the file names, but you're not changing the strings in your list to reflect the new file names. You can see this if you print allFiles. The above will make the necessary change for you.

Comment: thanks for your comment, got a novice question. I followed the step you had mentioned but find the file extension does not get added to the files before the loop. The same error is still being thrown. I have updated my initial post with the changes. Could you please advice as to where am I going wrong. Thanks

Comment: Oh no problem. The key is to 'add' the line above, not replace what you had. See edit above.

Comment: `allFiles` is a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), not an array.

Comment: You're right, wwii. I was using R terminology by accident and forgot that there is a difference. Edited for clarity.